# Proper Express error handling with promises and avoiding ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

So I've been looking through a bunch of stackoverflow posts, articles online, and https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html but can't seem to find the proper way to stop a promise and return the response to a user.

I currently have dependent async promises that Promise A needs to resolve before Promise B starts. If something goes wrong anywhere in there, I'd like to return different errors to the client using the `res.json()` method. Unfortunately, it seems no matter what I'm doing, after the `res` is sent to the client, then `catch(next)` is called which would then try to send the `res` to the client again with different headers. That leads to the `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` error.

I had also tried with just return statements but that seemed to just continue onto the next `.then()` which would pass whatever the return statement had.

index.js:

```
const errorFunc = (err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err);

  return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal error.' });
};
app.get('/scream/:screamId/like', FBAuth, likeScream, errorFunc);
```

The handler

```
exports.likeScream = (req, res, next) => {
  const likeDocument = db
    .collection('likes')
    .where('userHandle', '==', req.user.handle)
    .where('screamId', '==', req.params.screamId)
    .limit(1);

  const screamDocument = db.doc(`/screams/${req.params.screamId}`);

  return likeDocument
    .get()
    .then((data) => {
      if (!data.empty) {
        res
          .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
          .json({ error: 'User already liked scream' })
          .send();
        return Promise.reject(new Error('User already liked screams'));
      } else {
        return screamDocument;
      }
    })
    .then((doc) => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        res.status(404).json({ error: 'Scream not found' }).send();
        return Promise.reject(new Error('Scream not found'));
      }
      const likeCount = doc.data().likeCount++;
      return db.doc(`/screams/${req.params.screamId}`).update({ likeCount });
    })
    .then(() => {
      const likeDetails = {
        userHandle: req.user.handle,
        screamId: req.params.screamId,
      };
      return db.collection('likes').add(likeDetails);
    })
    .then(() => {
      return res.json({ message: 'Scream liked successfully.' });
    })
    .catch(next);
};
```

Note that most of this code was from following the https://github.com/hidjou/classsed-react-firebase-functions/blob/master/functions/handlers/screams.js tutorial for learning firebase and react. That code there seems to have this issue too.

So overall, what's the proper way to send out `res.sendStatus(XXX)` and stop an ongoing Promise? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't `res.send()` after `res.json()`

Comment: So I originally didn't have .send() after the .json() but was still getting the same error. The response to the client still is {     "error": "User already liked scream" }. Even with just the above written code, the error is thrown and the catch block calls the `errorFunc` which tries to send a response with other headers again.